# Error when publishing or saving an API in WSO2

Tags: java, mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 AM 1.9.0 and BAM 2.5.0, with JDK 1.7.0_79 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar.

When I try to save or publish an API in the API Publisher, an alert appears with "Error occurred while updating API".

In the "/wso2am-1.9.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log" file:

```
    ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() for servlet JaggeryServlet threw exception {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher}
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.addURLTemplates(ApiMgtDAO.java:6721)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.updateURLTemplates(ApiMgtDAO.java:6917)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.updateAPI(ApiMgtDAO.java:7022)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:547)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.manageAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:902)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPIDesign(APIProviderHostObject.java:733)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_6(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:125)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_31(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:101)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:123)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:541)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-07-22 17:52:14,663] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/publisher] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve}
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.addURLTemplates(ApiMgtDAO.java:6721)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.updateURLTemplates(ApiMgtDAO.java:6917)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.updateAPI(ApiMgtDAO.java:7022)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:547)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.manageAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:902)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPIDesign(APIProviderHostObject.java:733)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_6(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:125)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_31(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:101)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:123)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:541)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea about how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove all existing mysql connector jars from `[IS_HOME]/repository/components/dropins` and `[IS_HOME]/repository/components/lib` directories
2. Copy `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar` or `5.1.*` version to `[IS_HOME]/repository/components/lib` directory and restart IS.

Comment: Do you think the issue is related to mysql-connector version? If yes, have you provided correct steps to remove previous mysql-connector (1st step) and deploy a new mysql-connector (2nd step)?

Comment: This is working fine for `5.1.*` versions. I tested this with `5.1.23,5.1.36, 5.1.30.`. I think this issue is coming because of older mysql version which is not implemented `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream`. so its better check `dropins` folder and remove old mysql versions.

Comment: but he is already using mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar. Isn't it a 5.1.* version?

Comment: yes Rajkumar, you are correct. but dropins folder may have older versions. probably he tried with older version first and after that he used `5.1.36`. dropins folder is not cleaning older versions. it has several versions which we tried. so better to clean it and try.

Comment: Okay.. then you need to give correct steps. I have edited your answer now.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention about lib folder.Thanx Raj

Comment: Thanks Madura, I wasn't removing all the old stuff.